# Issues with Populating TableView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am having an issue displaying some data in a JavaFX Table View, here are the code snippets of my program.

FXML:

```
<Tab text="CoolTable">
     <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
           <children>
              <TableView fx:id="table" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="81.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="471.0">
                <columns>
                  <TableColumn id="ID" prefWidth="75.0" text=" ID" fx:id="ID" />
                  <TableColumn id="Name"  prefWidth="185.0" text="Name" fx:id="Name" />
                </columns>
              </TableView>
           </children>
        </AnchorPane>
     </content>
  </Tab>
```

Bean Class:

```
public class C {


private String Name;
private int ID;

public C(Integer ID, String Name) {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.ID = ID;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String cName) {
    this.Name = cName;
}

public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(int cID) {
    this.ID = cID;
}
```

}

And Finally the controller class:

```
 @FXML
private TableView<C> table;

@FXML
private TableColumn<C, Integer> ID;

@FXML
private TableColumn<C, String> Name;
```

.
.
.
.
.

```
public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {


    // initialize your logic here: all @FXML variables will have been injected


    ID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<C, Integer>("ID"));
    Name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<C, String>("Name"));

    table.setItems(getCDummy());

 public static ObservableList<C> getCDummy(){
    ObservableList<C> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    data.addAll(new C(1, "Jim"));
    data.addAll(new C(2, "James"));
    data.addAll(new C(3, "Joe"));

    return data;
}
```

I am not quite sure what is going wrong, as far as I can see the table should be populated with the date generated from the getCDummy method.

I know there are a lot of questions relating to JavaFX TableView problems here but I did look through them and could not find any solution to my problem.

Comment: use JavaFX properties. see [JavaFX properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm)

Comment: Would you mind elaborating and perhaps specifying exactly what it is that is causing the issue?

Comment: change the types in your C class. for exemple:private String Name; should be private StringProperty Name.

Comment: Are you having a totally blank table or table with hoverable rows with empty text.

Comment: I can click on the rows and select them but there is no data in them.

Answer (score 0):

How abou this:
FXML File:

```
 <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0"  fx:controller="issue.FXMLController" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
           <children>
              <TableView fx:id="table" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="81.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="471.0">
                <columns>
                  <TableColumn id="ID" prefWidth="75.0" text=" ID" fx:id="ID" />
                  <TableColumn id="Name"  prefWidth="185.0" text="Name" fx:id="Name" />
                </columns>
              </TableView>
           </children>
        </AnchorPane>
```

The controller class:

```
 public class FXMLController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private TableView<C> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<C, Integer> ID;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<C,String> Name;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        ID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<C, Integer>("ID"));
    Name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<C, String>("Name"));

    table.setItems(getCDummy());}

 public static ObservableList<C> getCDummy(){
    ObservableList<C> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    data.addAll(new C(1, "Jim"));
    data.addAll(new C(2, "James"));
    data.addAll(new C(3, "Joe"));

    return data;
    }    

}
```

this works fine for me

Comment: Still no use, I keep getting a blank Table

Comment: I already have those elements added to the root of the fxml file, I only posted a snippet from the actual file.